# Nodemailer does not send mail from Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

Good day,
I have simple Nodejs program that is using Nodemailer:

```
var syncSql = require('sync-mysql');             
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');   

var syncCon = new syncSql(
{ 
    host:'localhost', 
    user:'_nodeuser', 
    password:'_password', 
    database:'mydatabase'
});

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
{
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: 
    {
        user: '_email@gmail.com',
        pass: '_gmailAppPass'
    },
    logger: true
});

...
resp2 = syncCon.query(sql);

var mailOptions =
            {
                from:   '_email@gmail.com',
                to:      resp2.email,                       
                subject:'_email subject',     
                html:   '_email body'
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log('remind_old_action(): '+ error);
                } else {
                    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);   
                }
            });
```

on my local Win 11 machine it works:

```
[2023-03-20 11:33:08] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.9.0; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.9.0[client:6.9.0])
[2023-03-20 11:33:09] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.9.0[client:6.9.0]
[2023-03-20 11:33:10] DEBUG [0FD44uxJ0] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 173.194.76.108 [cache miss]
[2023-03-20 11:33:10] INFO  [0FD44uxJ0] Secure connection established to 173.194.76.108:465
[2023-03-20 11:33:11] DEBUG [0FD44uxJ0] SMTP handshake finished
[2023-03-20 11:33:11] INFO  [0FD44uxJ0] User "_email@gmail.com" authenticated
[2023-03-20 11:33:11] INFO  Sending message <c25b179b-d610-4a55-8cdd-d5605ac0ae00@gmail.com> to <_target_email>
[2023-03-20 11:33:12] INFO  [0FD44uxJ0] <501 bytes encoded mime message (source size 498 bytes)>
[2023-03-20 11:33:13] DEBUG [0FD44uxJ0] Closing connection to the server using "end"
Email sent: 250 2.0.0 OK  1679311993 v15-20020a05600c444f00b003edddce5b00sm4292772wmn.12 - gsmtp
[2023-03-20 11:33:13] INFO  [0FD44uxJ0] Connection closed
```

but when I run this program on Ubuntu 22.04 server, it does not work from there:

```
[2023-03-20 11:40:27] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.9.1; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.9.1[client:6.9.1])
[2023-03-20 11:40:27] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.9.1[client:6.9.1]
[2023-03-20 11:40:27] DEBUG [jZWnAXUE78U] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 172.253.63.108 [cache miss]
[2023-03-20 11:42:27] ERROR [jZWnAXUE78U] Connection timeout
[2023-03-20 11:42:27] DEBUG [jZWnAXUE78U] Closing connection to the server using "destroy"
[2023-03-20 11:42:27] ERROR Send Error: Connection timeout
remind_old_action(): Error: Connection timeout
```

It seems the problem is not with Nodemailer itself.
I have also tried from express server (app) - same situation. The express app and sending mails both work from local machine. Express app itself works from Ubuntu server, but sending mails is not.
I'm also using Nginx as a reverse proxy for express app, played with config, switched it on/off - sending emails does not work in either case. Nodemailer can't connect to smtp.gmail.com, gives an error after 120 sec of waiting.
What else could I check?

UPD: I have enabled 2FA on google account and created a "less secure" 16-char apps password. It works correctly from local win machine, no problem with authentication, but time outs on ubuntu server.

**SOLVED**: "It's a trap!" (c)

The issue was that the ports 25/465 were blocked by cloud provider (Hetzner) and I unfortunately couldn't imagine this and thought the problem was on my side.

Comment: $ sudo ufw status  
  
Status: inactive

Comment: You didn't actually write how did you solve this issue on Hetzner? 
What is the exact nodemailer config that you used if you managed to overcome this?

Comment: I wrote to Hetzner support asking them to open the ports 25/465 for me, convincing them I'm not spammer :) they have opened the ports and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are use gmail service for send mail, so you can create **16 digit password** of your Gmail and this password is use

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
{
    service: 'gmail',
    auth:
    {
        user: '_email@gmail.com',
        pass: '16 digit _gmailAppPass'
    },
    logger: true
});
```

Comment: yes that's correct, I have enabled 2FA on google account and created a 16-char apps password. It works correctly from local machine, as seen in logs, sending mails and they are received at target mailboxes. 
But the same code does not work from ubuntu server, it simply does not connect to smtp.gmail.com.  I have also tried yahoo mail, and there I'm getting auth error (on local machine), but timeout on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Ubuntu 22.04 server's firewall settings, and allow SMTP and DNS traffic.

```
sudo ufw allow 53/tcp
sudo ufw allow 53/udp
sudo ufw allow out 25/tcp
sudo ufw allow out 25/udp
sudo ufw reload
```

After allowing those ports nodemailer started working for me. Also try disabling your firewall completely to see if it will send any emails.

Comment: Firewall was disabled on my machine, but these ports (25 and 465) were blocked by hoster (Hetzner). I did not expect this trap and was searching for solution on my side.